# Maple : polynomial in two variables

Tags: polynomial-math, maple, polynomials, inequality

I have a polynomial f(x,y) with rational coefficients.  I want to rigorously verify that f(x,y) >= 0 for 0 <= x <= 1 and 0 <= y <= 1.

How can I do it (using Maple or otherwise)?

EDIT:  The degree-12 example I had could be written as a sum of 23 terms of the form $x^i(1-x)^jy^k(1-x)^l$ with positive coefficients. I'd be interested in knowing whether a proof like that is always possible and if there is an algorithm or canned Maple code for carrying it out. I used linear programming, which was a pain.

Comment: How big is the degree of polynomial? How many terms does it have? There are two different approaches: calculus and algebra. Calculus: examine the critical points and boundary values. Algebraic approach: try to write f as a sum of squares.of polynomials. The latter actually proves f>=0 *everywhere*. If that's not true, you can use a substitution: x = u^2/(u+1)^2; y=v^2/(1+v^2). After this substitution you get  a rational function of u,v; its denominator is positive so can be cleared out. The new polynomial g(u,v) will be >=0 everywhere if and only if the original one was >=0 on that square.

Comment: @Famous : The degree is 12 and finding the critical points is hard. Your second method is nice, though it might need squares of rational functions rather than squares of polynomials (unless that's only needed for 3 or more variables, see Hilbert's 17th problem). I'll edit my question to indicate how I actually solved it.

Comment: I can partly answer your edited question: such a representation is not always possible. Consider f(x,y)=(x-1/2)^2+(y-1/2)^2. Any term of the form x^i(1-x)^jy^k(1-x)^l has a strictly positive value at (1/2,1/2), but f has zero value there. So, f cannot be written as a linear combination of such terms with positive coefficients.

Comment: Generally, I think this is a too mathematical question for SO, which doesn't even support latex markup. A better place to ask it may be [scicomp.se].